# 1 Dimensional sorted Array: KD-Tree vs Binary Search

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tree

Just to verify, am I correct, that if:

- I have a **sorted, one dimensional** array.
- A nearest neighbor search using a KD-Tree will always be at best as fast as using a binary search on that array? (For normal search of course the same)
- The same goes for range search (getting all elements in range x..y).
- The only advantage that I may have with a KD-Tree is when there is frequent insertion / deletion of the data.

This has been asked for Binary Trees and N-Dimensions in general, but I want to know this for the **KD-Tree** and ***1*** Dimensional data specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A nearest neighbor search using a KD-Tree will always be at best as fast as using a binary search on that array? (For normal search of course the same)

Correct. If the KD-Tree is slightly degenerated (through update operations) you will be worse off.

> The same goes for range search (getting all elements in range x..y).

Correct. Once you find the smallest value greater than x with binary search you can just scan until you hit y. In a KD-tree you will have to walk through all the nodes where the keys in your range  are located.

> The only advantage that I may have with a KD-Tree is when there is
>   frequent insertion / deletion of the data.

It depends what you mean by advantage.

Insertion and deletion is faster in KD-Trees than in sorted arrays.

However, the search on the KD-tree will become slower with more insertions/deletions, since the KD-tree will degenerate (if you only use the base KD-tree without adaptations for updates). The binary search will stay at O(log n).

Not your question but, if you are operating in 1D you will most likely use best of both worlds which means [Red-Black Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), [B+-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) or something similar.